# What would cause an interactive git rebase to fail without modifying the todo?

Tags: git

Let's say I want to rebase the master branch of a repo with a long and complicated history of merges. I want to go back about 100 commits to commit `$SHA`

I can either do this with `git rebase -i $SHA` or `git rebase -i $SHA --rebase-merges`. If I'm understanding correctly, the latter includes merge commits, while the former does not.

In either case, I'll get the `TODO` opened, and just save and quit without changing anything.

In both situations, the rebase fails. In the case of `--rebase-merges`, it fails with the following error:

```
hint: Could not execute the todo command
hint: 
hint:     label #10:-Merge-dev
hint: 
hint: It has been rescheduled; To edit the command before continuing, please
hint: edit the todo list first:
hint: 
hint:     git rebase --edit-todo
hint:     git rebase --continue
```

In the case without that flag, I'm under the impression that it would 'flatten' the git history, thus removing the merge commits. However, this also leads to well over 50 merge conflicts, which would take an absurd amount of time to solve by hand.

I'm not here really looking for a way to fix these issues, I'm more curious as to why rebasing while changing literally nothing in the TODO will fail.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is due to your label containing a hash mark, which is likely being interpreted as a comment.  You'd probably want to adjust the label and the uses of it such that they don't contain a hash mark, and then try the rebase again.

If these TODO entries are created by Git, you might want to report this to the Git list as a bug; there was recently some discussion about invalid label names, and you may want to check that someone sent in a patch to fix that.

Comment: I thought that too, but I changed my git comment char to `!` instead of `#`. I assume that the rebase might not handle that properly?

Otherwise, you're right, the labels are autogenerated by git. I didn't touch the TODO at all

Comment: It's possible that it's not handling that correctly.  We've had issues with that before.